# Automate Elasticsearch optimization

Tags: machine-learning, optimization, large-data

I am planning to do a thesis in the Elasticsearch(a search engine based on the Lucene library) parameter optimization using some machine learning or optimization algorithm(automate the optimization of Elasticsearch parameters/settings based on current data/conditions). Which Machine learning or optimization algorithm do you suggest for it?

Comment: There are a number of suggestions in the duplicate thread, and many more available as a search https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=tune+hyperparameter If you have a different question or something more specific about how Elasticsearch works, please edit to clarify or ask a new question